# Получить MAC-адреса устройств

Tags: linux, c, сокет, mac-address, syscall

Нужно получить MAC-адреса устройств; нашёл и адаптировал уже существующее на stackoverflow решение:

```c
bool get_mac_address(unsigned char mac[6])
{
    struct ifconf ifc;
    char buff[1024];

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sock == -1) goto fail;

    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof (buff);
    ifc.ifc_buf = buff;
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == -1) goto fail;

    bool is_success = false;
    for (struct ifreq* i = ifc.ifc_req; i != ifc.ifc_req + ifc.ifc_len/sizeof(*i); ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(i->ifr_name, "lo"))
            continue;
        struct ifreq ifr;
        strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, i->ifr_name);
        if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == 0) {
            memcpy(mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);
            close(sock);
            return true;
        }
    }
fail:
    close(sock);
    return false;
}
```

Однако, оно работает (и не удивительно) только при активном интернет-соединении.

**Можно ли сделать так, чтобы получить mac-адреса посредством похожих функций и при отсутствии подключении к нету?
Под похожими функциями я имею в виду не простое чтение с файлов вроде /sys/class/net/.../address, а обращение к каким-то syscallам.**

Comment: обращение к "файлам вроде" - нормальная практика.

Comment: `getifaddrs()`, не?

Comment: если хочешь тоже самое сделать на голых системных вызовов, то смотри `man 7 rtnetlink`, внимание на `RTM_GETLINK`...

Comment: Учтите ещё, что далеко не у всякого типа сетевого адаптера в общем случае есть MAC-адрес.

Comment: Почему только при активном? У меня вроде без инета тоже снимается мак

Comment: Попробуй sock_dgram

Comment: Причём тут **активное** соединение?! Где в Вашей программе кто-то с кем-то устанавливает соединение? Тем более - интернет! А если в локалке, то и МАС-адреса нет ?!!!